# Text isn't display in a label due to selection of font

Tags: iphone, fonts, uilabel

I am using "American Typewriter" font in my iPhone app. I used to display some message into label. When I checked it into simulator it works very fine. But when I test it on my iPod 4G its not showing that message. Then I used set default font for my label. Then again I tested it at both side and I am wondering its working fine.

I want to use "American Typewriter" which is provided by XCode. But why can't I use it with my application?

I google it about this problem but they all showing solution for custom fonts.

Help me ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I have checked is that AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight is not available in the iphone font library so change this to regular. 
From this [image] to [image]

P.S. Haven't checked on Device please check it.